# IE7 Content Advisor Custom Ratings file error

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 7 on Windows XP SP3

I'm try to enable Content Advisor in Internet Options under Content.  I have a custom Ratings System file that I want to use.  When I try to add the contentadvisor.rat Rating System file I get the following error.

[image]

My contentadvisor.rat file:

```
(
  (PICS-version 1.0)
  (name "contentadvisor")
  (description "A fake rating service that doesn't rate anything.")
  (rating-system "http://website.com")
  (rating-service "http://website.com")
  (category
    (transmit-as "Please Use The Approved Sites Tab Instead!")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-created the contentadvisor.rat file in Notepad.  Instead of copying the contents in I retyped everything and saved it.  IE 7 does not give a syntax error on the new file, even the contents of the file look exactly the same as it did before.